# Is there a bump?

Tags: code-golf, number, array, decision-problem

Given a list of positive integers determine if there is an element that is either greater than its two neighbors or less than its two neighbors (a "bump").  To be clear a bump can never be the first or last item of the list because they only have one neighbor.

Your program should output one of two consistent values each corresponding to either a list with no bumps or a list with bumps.  What the values are is unimportant you may choose them yourself.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

### Test cases

```
[] -> False
[1] -> False
[1,2] -> False
[1,2,1] -> True
[1,2,2] -> False
[1,2,3] -> False
[1,2,2,1] -> False
[1,2,2,3] -> False
[1,2,1,2] -> True
[1,3,2] -> True
[3,1,2] -> True
[2,2,2] -> False
```

Comment: Test Case Request: Numbers other than 0-1-2-3, also negatives allowed/disallowed?

Comment: Suggested test case: `[1,3,3]` (ensures that answers using Dennis's algorithm take the sign of the increments rather than just using the increments themselves)

Comment: @ETHproductions Isn't that already covered by `[1,2,2]`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @NicHartley, the deltas of `[1,2,2]` are the same as the signs of those deltas but that's not the case with `[1,3,3]`.

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
IṠIỊẠ
```

Returns **0** if there's a bump, **1** if not.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z4c4Fng93dz3cteD/4fZHTWsi//@PjtVRiDYEEzpGUEoHxkeIGMNFkCQRonC9xhCGkY4BUB0A)

#### How it works

```
IṠIỊẠ  Main link. Argument: A (integer array)

I      Increments; take all forward differences of A.
 Ṡ     Take the signs.
       The signs indicate whether the array is increasing (1), decreasing (-1), or
       constant at the corresponding point. A 1 followed by a -1 indicates a local
       maximum, a -1 followed by a 1 a local minimum.
  I    Increments; take the forward differences again.
       Note that 1 - (-1) = 2 and (-1) - 1 = -2. All other seven combinations of
       signs map to -1, 0, or 1.
   Ị   Insignificant; map each difference d to (-1 ≤ d ≤ 1).
    Ạ  All; return 1 if all differences are insignificant, 0 if not.
```

Comment: What is "Increments?".  What is being incremented and what does that do?

Comment: @WheatWizard I think that this is the equivalent of 05AB1E's deltas (¥) command: an array [n0, n1, n2, n3] is poped and the array [n1-n0, n2-n1, n3-n2] is pushed.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

Returns a boolean.

```js
a=>a.some(x=n=>x*(x=a<n|-(a>(a=n)))<0)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>a.some(x=n=>x*(x=a<n|-(a>(a=n)))<0)

console.log(f([]))              // False
console.log(f([1]))             // False
console.log(f([1,2]))           // False
console.log(f([1,2,1]))         // True
console.log(f([1,2,2]))         // False
console.log(f([1,2,3]))         // False
console.log(f([1,2,2,1]))       // False
console.log(f([1,2,2,3]))       // False
console.log(f([1,2,1,2]))       // True
console.log(f([1,3,2]))         // True
console.log(f([2,0,1]))         // True
console.log(f([2,2,2]))         // False
console.log(f([-4,100000,89]))  // True
```

#### How?

We use **a** to store the previous value of **n**. We set **x** to **1** if **a < n**, **-1** if **a > n** or **0** if **a = n**. And we test whether **old_x * x < 0**, which is only possible if (**old_x = 1** and **x = -1**) or (**old_x = -1** and **x = 1**).

Because **x** is initialized to the anonymous callback function of **some()**, it is coerced to **NaN** during the first iteration, which makes the test falsy.

Comment: This will throw in strict mode.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Well, 99% of JS golfed code will throw in strict mode just because of undeclared variables. PPCG and codereview doesn't mix well. :P

Comment: That's fair, I'm not really much for golf.

Comment: Then why comment on it lol

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
any(<0).f(*).f(-)
f a b=zipWith a b$tail b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfbhvzPzGvUsPGQFMvTUMLROhqcqUpJCok2VZlFoRnlmSA2ColiZk5Ckn/cxMz82wLijLzSlRyEwsU0qOjY3WiDUFYxwhC6kB5cL4xjI@QgYvBdBmDaSMdA6Ca2P//ktNyEtOL/@smFxQAAA)

### Explanation

First we have the function `f` that takes a binary function and a list and applies the binary function to every adjacent pair in the list.

Then our main function applies `f(-)` to the input list.  This calculates the difference list.  We then apply `f(*)` to the list to multiply every adjacent pair.  Lastly we ask if any pair is less than zero.

A number in the end list can only be negative if it is the product of a negative and positive number from the difference list.  Thus in order to produce a negative entry (and then return true) the original list must switch from increasing to decreasing or vice versa, that is it must have a bump.

Comment: Nice way to deal with the empty list!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y,z,*t:0>(y-x)*(z-y)or f(y,z,*t)
```

Returns *True* if there's a bump, errors if there isn't. ([allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/12012))

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRoUKnUqdKR6vEysBOo1K3QlNLo0q3UjO/SCFNAyKh@T8NyCtRyMxTiI7VUYg2BBM6RlBKB8ZHiBjDRZAkEaJwvcYQhjFMxAhsiBUXZ0lRJZDkLCjKzCsBugPoBi7O1Irk1IIShZDKglTXoqL8IoQCt8Sc4tT/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) with Image Package, <s>34</s> 32 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to [@StewieGriffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)!*

```matlab
@(x)0||prod(im2col(diff(x),2))<0
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0LToKamoCg/RSMz1yg5P0cjJTMtDSiqY6SpaWPwP00jOlaTC0gaQilrIzjDGiGGLGqMJIqiBFkGyRxjGNMYIWoEMfI/AA)

#### Explanation

Computes consecutive differences, arranges them in sliding blocks of length 2, obtains the product of each block, and tests if any such product is negative.

Comment: [`0||prod(...)`](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0LToKamoCg/RSMz1yg5P0cjJTMtDSiqY6SpaWPwP00jOlaTC0gaQilrIzjDGiGGLGqMJIqiBFkGyRxjGNMYIWoEMfI/AA) saves 2 bytes. You could also skip the entire `any` part, and use the default truthy/falsy definition to [save 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY/LCoMwEEXXna/IzgSC1LirFbrqF3QnLiQPGLCNxL5A/PY0BNtiXMxizpy5k1h5757amzrPc3@ibzY4qyhehbQ9VWhMQFwwdtx7SWoyQdNykp27ftRZBU2x7rhIex6Ni3v8wFYpN2RZS9jWWw7@48s1KFNDrB8AcwVgrCOI4XPFwdnXSCWDHRpiqJwQeTEzThSOA21iSvAyTuJIzG2Y6RD0FWJqauibglD@Aw).

Comment: Darn, saving 5 bytes will make your solution shorter than mine :( Nice use of the image package. I didn't know it was on TIO.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Since the challenge requires two consistent values I cannot remove `any`. Thanks for the `0||` idea!

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
f(p:r@(c:n:_))=(c-p)*(c-n)>0||f r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02jwKrIQSPZKs8qXlPTViNZt0BTC0jmadoZ1NSkKRT9z03MzFOwVSgoyswrUVBRSFOINtRRMNJRMAaThrH/AQ)

`True` if there's a bump, errors if there's not.

Comment: ``l`zip3`tail l$drop 2l`` is just a hair shorter. I wonder if pattern matching is somehow even shorter?

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 39 bytes

```
{so~(.[1..*]Zcmp$_)~~/'re L'|'s M'/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/uji/TkMv2lBPTys2Kjm3QCVes65OX70oVcFHvUa9WMFXXb/2f3FipYKSSryCrZ1CdZqCSnytkkJafpFCdKyOgo2hHYhQMIJSCjA@QsQYLoIkiRCF6zWGMIwUDIDq/gMA)

`$_` is the list argument to this anonymous function.  `.[1..*]` is the same list, but with the first element dropped.  `Zcmp` zips the two lists together with the `cmp` operator, resulting in a list of `Order` values.  For example, for an input list `1, 2, 2, 2, 1` this would result in the list `More, Same, Same, Less`.

Now we just need to know whether that list contains two adjacent elements `More, Less` or `Less, More`.  The trick I used is to convert the list to a space-delimited string with `~`, then test whether it contains either substring `re L` or `s M`.  (The first one can't be just `e L` because `Same` also ends with an "e".)

The smart match operator returns either a `Match` object (if the match succeeded) or `Nil` (if it didn't), so `so` converts whatever it is into a boolean value.

Comment: You can replace `.[1..*]` with `.skip` and the regex with `/re.L|s.M/`. You can then replace the smartmatch with function composition with `o`. Also, your byte count is wrong? [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2l6/KFXPp6ZYz1e/Nr9arzg7s0AhKjm3QCW@9n9xYqWCkkq8gq2dQnWaAlBESSEtv0ghOlZHwcbQDkQoGEEpBRgfIWIMF0GSRIjC9RpDGEYKBkB1/wE)

Answer (score 4):

## R, 48 bytes

```
function(x)any(apply(embed(diff(x),2),1,prod)<0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjMxr1IjsaAgp1IjNTcpNUUjJTMtDSisY6SpY6hTUJSfomljoPk/TSNZw1DHCCiqyQVjG8LZhkhsIxQZIBtJjwmQZ6Kp@R8A)

How it works step-by-step using c(1,4,1,4) as example:

```
> x=c(1,4,1,4)
> diff(x)
[1]  3 -3  3
> embed(diff(x),2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -3    3
[2,]    3   -3
> apply(embed(diff(x),2),1,prod)
[1] -9 -9
> any(apply(embed(diff(x),2),1,prod)<0)
[1] TRUE
```

As a bonus, here is a solution of similar length and concept using package `zoo`:

```
function(x)any(zoo::rollapply(diff(x),2,prod)<0)
```

Comment: neat! Note to self: remember `embed` exists. It's too bad that `rowProds` and `colProds` doesn't exist as aliases in R.

Comment: @Giuseppe out of desperation i actually checked if they existed :) but indeed just `rowSums` and `rowMeans`...

Comment: well, at least looking through the docs, `.colSums` will reshape the input into a matrix based on additional inputs which probably has a golfing application somewhere....now I just have to find one!

Comment: @Guiseppe: Have a look at the functions in `matrixStats` package.

Comment: @MichaelM Unfortunately because of the length of the package name it doesn't make it competitive (57 bytes: `function(x)any(matrixStats::colProds(embed(diff(x),2)))<0`). But for anything other than code golf, this package is indeed a treasure trove.

Comment: @plannapus: My comment was purely unrelated of playing golf - my bad.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>55</s> 46 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.each_cons(3).any?{|x,y,z|(y-x)*(y-z)>0}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5LDoMwDET3OYWXpDKoJGvoQVBUJaiIDR81RSIkOXvKp6FsrPHzjO33pExoipCW0srsJev2WQ@9TjjNZG8e1s1ocHGJSWd6W@tCy7v3QU3daKCAigBUOTLMBZ4SWWx4lHynRBCiu2H4tDH6M57h/5aL5Bd6PXRO2O7fto@wf5Z1crROOWgqJfxKj6sH1hvWwocv)

A lambda accepting an array and returning boolean.

-9 bytes: Replace `(x<y&&y>z)||(x>y&&y<z)` with `(y-x)*(y-z)>0` (thanks to [GolfWolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3527/golfwolf))

```ruby
->a{
  a.each_cons(3)              # Take each consecutive triplet
    .any?{ |x,y,z|            # Destructure to x, y, z
      (y-x)*(y-z) > 0         # Check if y is a bump
    }
}
```

Comment: I _think_ you can use `|` instead of `||`, saving you 1 byte.

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY5LDoMwDET3OYWXpDKoJGvoQVBUJaiIDR81RSIkOXvKp6FsrPHzjO33pExoipCW0srsJev2WQ@9TjjNZG8e1s1ocHGJSWd6W@tCy7v3QU3daKCAigBUOTLMBZ4SWWx4lHynRBCiu2H4tDH6M57h/5aL5Bd6PXRO2O7fto@wf5Z1crROOWgqJfxKj6sH1hvWwocv)

Comment: Save 1 byte with '0<(y-x)*y-=z'

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
MatchQ[{___,x_,y_,z_,___}/;x<y>z||x>y<z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@983sSQ5IzC6Oj4@XqciXqcyXqcqXgfIqdW3rrCptKuqqamwq7Spiv0fUJSZVxKtrKOgpKBrp6Cko5AWrRwbq6CmoO@gUF1dq6NQbQgmdBSMYLSOgiGCiSRqjCSKqgZFDskoYyjTGCFqBDW19j8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```r
function(x)any(abs(diff(sign(diff(c(NA,x)))))>1,na.rm=T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDBasQgEADQu18hnkYYCia3gIVeeuxpb64Ua3UrWBOiLSml355u12xJms5FeTPMDDPOXs7@LdkS@gQTN@kDzFOG5@A95HBK9Wfh4Q4n/hO3ApO5GV/lgc/l0ZrsMpU0hlyAkstjgSNd4p7jFcWvrhGbhbeItfqwxVr7p7L9D2uDHbZ7rBtsBrXLoBW2KPbYrFYinBDfjxBoSFR00aVTeYHlQJx/EmpNAeY7hv7KSgWtlRJac2THQt00nNPbZKP1JfduYu6oYjiYXBzQXQu0fYxmyE4yZOelmD4mhtkNkjFOvuZv)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

Comment: You can get rid of the braces `{}` for -2 bytes.

Comment: additionally, I think that you can port [Stewie Griffin's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155844/67312) approach for [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZBBa4QwEIXv/oohPWwCWah6E9xjT0tP7ckNJcbJGupGMbF1Kf3tVtQua@1cMnzv8eaRdtDpoDurvKkt7Zm0VypzRwujNXXmbOetZ@McQjb4NyUdOkihMs5TCKbHdhdsjaKPjMMyT@P6AHhp/HWywn4PijIoanR25@Gzbt8hRyU7h2D8zoGE59fjEVrpS2zBl9KOqKi7vML5iqLhLX@Mv0EeLXgN@ex@WcPZ@8cZ/wfngA2Mt3BusDoUL4fuYMzDLYzuKgUsCHTdUgPGQphUaM@@pMuPM/YVgJKeEp0Qrn9xlhkhsiwUgnFy8oB9M8prMRJi0j5k5RLICG@k80hhE8FVXVWycZgSTsZSRJws4Q6blBAWfA8/ "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe, I think Stewie ported my method, with the difference that mine can properly handle the empty vector as listed in the test cases. Matlab is a bit more lenient with empty vectors compared to R.

Comment: `c()` is `NULL` which is not the same as the empty vector of integers, `integer(0)`, whereas in MATLAB `[]` is a `double` by default, but if you want to keep it this way, that's perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
±V<0Ẋ*Ẋ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkKtR/KipsUjz0Lb/hzaG2Rg83NWlBcS6////j47lijYEYR0jCKkD5cH5xjA@QgYuBtNlDKaNoXwjqG4jqAoA)

### Explanation

```
±V<0Ẋ*Ẋ-  Implicit input, say [2,5,5,1,4,5,3]
      Ẋ-  Consecutive differences: [3,0,-4,3,1,-2]
    Ẋ*    Consecutive products: [0,0,-12,3,-2]
 V<0      Is any of them negative? Return 1-based index: 3
±         Sign (to make output consistent): 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>16</strike> 15 bytes

-1 byte thanks to FrownyFrog

```
1 e.0>2*/\2-/\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DRVS9QzsjLT0Y4x09WNi/2tyKXClJmfkK6QpGKgYwJiGcIaCERITRRxVxhhFBk0hqiyKmcYIjjGyDEiX0X8A)

### Original:  16 bytes

```
0>[:<./2*/\2-/\]
```

`2-/\]` - differences of each adjacent items

`2*/\`  -  products of each adjacent items

`[:<./`  - the minimum

`0>`     - is negative?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DeyirWz09I209GOMdPVjYv9rcilwpSZn5CukKRioGMCYhnCGghESE0UcVcYYRQZNIaosipnGCI4xsgxIl9F/AA)

Comment: Hello ! Could this not be shortened to this simpler explicit form  0><./2*/\2-/\ (13 bytes) ?

Comment: @Mathias Dolidon This works in the interpreter but here in PPCG it's common to provide a function (J verb) if there is some input. If the verb is tacit one, we don't count the assignment `f=.` bytes. Please have in mind that I'm relatively new user :)

Comment: So am I, and you've clarified the rule for me. Thanks ! :)

Comment: `1 e.0>2*/\2-/\]`

Comment: @ FrownyFrog  Thank you! It seems that I rarely use e.  :)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>108</s> <s>104</s> <s>101</s> <s>86</s> <s>84</s> <s>79</s> 72 bytes

```java
a->{int i=a.length,p=0;for(;i-->1;)i|=p*(p=a[i]-a[i-1])>>-1;return-i>1;}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.
-13 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lZExb8MgEIX3/IobcWWc2t6K7LFbs6Sb5eHikISEHAjjVJHr3@7SpJXaLUiAdPDx7j044gW5sZKO29Pcaex7eENF4wJAkZduh52E1XcJsDFGSyToWDhqWsBEhP0pzDB6j151sAKCCmbk9RggUBVmWtLeH1JbPYudcUwozutcJOqzsk/MVtioloeF521S1zwXTvrBEVcBmmZxV7fDRgf1nyYXo7ZwDjbZ2jtF@6bF5G5xuYR3N/jD9eVWrq@9l@fMDD6zAfSaGGUdI/kBtwhjnhZpPiW3II/iaRFzoYzBy3/qv4leUffy0UQR3qJyxz1SJF5Gqsf@WVSH4o//aTHNXw)

Comment: [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##lVGxbsMgFNzzFW@EyjjG3orssVuzpJvl4cUhCSkBC@NUkeVvd4nTSu0WJBAc3Ht3B2e8IrOdNOf959xq7Ht4R2XGFYAyXroDthI2dwiws1ZLNNCScFU3gFSE8ynMMHqPXrWwAQMlzMiqMZBAlZhqaY7@xHjiykwcrCNCVVxQdSBZRbBWjDUsLA19uaNlz3hDqSu5cNIPzoCrMjHN4qHUDTsdlH4Er1bt4RIsk613yhzrBunD7noNH27wp9vrAre33stLagefdoHotSEmbYmRX7DEGXmSJ3yiS6hn6UkeU1DE0It/3X8TvaHu5bOJIrxF5Y57pEh6Edk99s@iFPI//qfVNH8D). I changed the iteration order (going down), swapped the two multiplication operands and then could remove a superfluous `-1`.

Comment: 79 bytes: `a->{int i=a.length;for(;i-->2;)i|=(a[i]-a[--i])*(a[i]-a[i-1])>>-1;return-~i|3;}` (returns `-1` for truthy cases, `3` for falsey cases) - or, if using the presence/absence of an exception as return value 55 bytes: `a->{for(int i=0;++i>0;)i|=(a[i-1]-a[i])*(a[i]-a[i+1]);}`

Comment: 72 bytes: `a->{int i=a.length,p=0;for(;i-->1;)i|=p*(p=a[i]-a[i-1])>>-1;return-i>1;}`

Answer (score 3):

## PostgreSQL 173 bytes

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(a)a,x>j and x>k OR x<least(j,k)FROM(SELECT a,x,lag(x,1,x)OVER(w)j,lead(x,1,x)OVER(w)k FROM d WINDOW w AS(PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY xn))d ORDER BY 1,2 DESC;
     a     | c 
-----------+---
 {1}       | f
 {1,2}     | f
 {1,2,1}   | t
 {1,2,1,2} | t
 {1,2,2}   | f
 {1,2,2,1} | f
 {1,2,2,3} | f
 {1,2,3}   | f
 {1,3,2}   | t
 {2,2,2}   | f
 {3,1,2}   | t
(11 rows)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL but you might be able to reduce the amount of whitespace you use.  In general most languages don't require most of the kinds of spacing you use.

Comment: @WheatWizard it's the sample data into the database, it's irrelevant.

Comment: What's your code then?  We don't allow the input to be inserted directly into the code instead of the input. If that is the case here you ought to rewrite it so that it takes input via a [standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

Comment: @WheatWizard from the link you provided, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/23085

Comment: Ok if that's the input format you are using that's fine then.  Best of luck golfing here,  it's nice to see people golfing in less commonly used languages.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

```
ä- mÌäa d>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///ASXYXcwz2HlyQqpNgZ/v8fbahjpAPEsQA) | [Test cases](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9C6w0t0FXIP9xxekqiQYmf4/390dKwOV7RhrI4CkNQxAnN0jHTgAgghYxgDRRYkDGWDtYPZxlCWMVzMCGxSLJduEAA)

This uses Dennis's [algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155800/61613)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
ä- ä* d<0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///ASXYXDS7QUUmwM/v@PNtQx1jGMBQA)

A mashup of Oliver's answer with the approach used by several other answers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 39 bytes

```
Any&:&{_*~?Sum[__]}@Slices&2@Sign@Delta
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3vkpqWmZcarZKm898xr1LNSq06XqvOPrg0Nzo@PrbWITgnMzm1WM3IITgzPc/BJTWnJPF/LBcXTFdJso5CNJcCEETH6kBoQzhDxwiJqYMsjipjjCKDphBVFsVMYwTHGFnGCGwBVyzQnX6pqSnF0SoFBcnpsVwBRZl5JSGpxSXOicWpxdFpOgolybH/AQ)

Pretty happy with how this turned out.

### Explanation

This is a composition of four functions:

```
Delta
Sign
Slices&2
Any&:&{_*~?Sum[__]}
```

`Delta` gets the differences between elements. =

Then, `Sign` is applied to each difference, giving us an array of `1`s, `0`s, and `-1`s. =

Then, `Slices&2` gives all slices of length two from the array, giving all pairs of differences.

Finally, `Any&:&{_*~?Sum[__]}` is equivalent to, for input `x`:

```
Any[&{_*~?Sum[__]}, x]
Any[[el] -> { el[0] and not (el[0] + el[1] = 0) }, x]
```

This searches for elements which sum to zero but are not zero. If any such pair of elements exist, then there is a bump.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 33 bytes

```matlab
@(x)0||abs(diff(sign(diff(x))))>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/fCoMgFIev51OcuxQksO4WjV3tCXYXXTTTcWDU0P0Jomd3zjUoEwTP73znU3v5aF7K6TJNU3ekA2sulraoNbV47X6ngfl1EE5CCSOpag7JqblZlRSkEuuKZ3HNA3E2zznIeb5Btsk8FmVbbr5wqV8FeUx8NYs3kqkgRPcGEP3nxN70b0slIzvUoKkcEbmYGIcW7Z1WweK5hENoZVPte8qL/kCwxoTqWuK3@wA)

#### Explanation:

```matlab
@(x)                           % Anonymous function taking x as input
                  diff(x)       % Takes the difference between consecutive elements
             sign(diff(x))      % The sign of the differences
        diff(sign(diff(x)))     % The difference between the signs
    abs(diff(sign(diff(x)))>1   % Check if the absolute value is 2
@(x)abs(diff(sign(diff(x)))>1   % Output as matrices that are treated truthy or falsy
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
dZSd|1>a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyUqOKXG0C7xv716SFFpqnqtultiTnGq@v9oQx1jIDTUMdAxjAUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
¥ü‚P0‹Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvn/0NLDex41zAoweNSwM@p/pdLh/Qq6dgqH9yvpxPyPjuWKNgRhHSMIqQPlwfnGMD5CBi4G02UMpo2hfCO4bmOwSl1DHQMdXSMIC6goFgA)

**Explanation**

```
¥         # calculate delta's
 ü‚       # pair each element with the next element
   P      # product of each pair
    0‹    # check each if less than 0
      Z   # max
```

Comment: Wasn't there a 1-byte alternative to `0‹` that basically checks the number for a negative sign?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: `d` used to check that top of stack only contained `[0-9]`, which is the opposite of what we want here. But now it's more intelligent and negative/floats are also counted as numbers.

Comment: Ahhhh... coulda sworn `a` saw the `negative` sign and returned true or something... But I think you're right, I'm remembering your `d` trick.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
s₃.¬≤₁∧¬≥₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/hRU7PeoTWPOpc8amp81LEcxFwKZP7/H22oY6QDxLEA)

Succeeds (`true.`) if there is a bump, and fails (`false.`) if there is no bump.

#### Explanation

This is fairly readable already:

```
s₃.           There is a substring of the input…
  .¬≤₁        …which is not non-decreasing…
      ∧       …and…
       ¬≥₁    …which is not non-increasing
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
s₃s₂ᶠ-ᵐ×<0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/hRUzMQNz3ctkD34dYJh6fbGPxXVYiO5QIShhBSxwhG68BFkMSMEWLI8kjiCBOMoSxjuJgR2Kz/QDkFIx0Fw1gA)

Not nearly as neat and elegant as @Fatalize's existing 10 byte answer, but it works!

```
s₃   % There exists a substring of three elements [I,J,K] in the array such that

s₂ᶠ  % When it's split into pairs [[I,J],[J,K]]

-ᵐ   % And each difference is taken [I-J, J-K]

×    % And those differences are multiplied (I-J)*(J-K)
     % (At a bump, one of those will be negative and the other positive. 
     % At other places, both differences will be positive, or both negative, 
     %  or one of them 0 - ultimately resulting in a non-negative product.)

<0   % The product is negative
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>15</s> <s>19</s> 20 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer*

```apl
{2>≢⍵:0⋄2∊|2-/×2-/⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqI7tHnYse9W61MnjU3WL0qKOrxkhX//B0IAEUrAUqUnjUu4YrTcGQi0vdVp0LxFIwgpBw2hjGB6qCsYyR1cPFYXqNwbSRggGSDiAJAA)

**1** for bump, **0** for no bump.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives an error for `⍬`, while it should return `0` instead (or throw an error for all falsy inputs).

Comment: Oh, and, if you fix the issue, `0∊2>` can be `2∊` instead for -2 bytes.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer temporary quick fix, thanks

Comment: Still fails for singleton lists

Comment: @H.PWiz A possible fix is to replace `⍬≡` with `2>≢` for just 1 extra byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
lambda l:any(p>c<n or p<c>n for p,c,n in zip(l,l[1:],l[2:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcY7DoAgEAXAq7wSkm3AjqAXUQrEEElw3RgbvTx@msnIda4725b7qdW4zUtEdZEvJUPyjP2A@DQw8jdKxCiMu4iqVEfjwqt1QesmR@ETWY2GYAndrwm6PQ)

Pretty much the same thing, thought it would be shorter though...

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l[3:]and(l[0]>l[1]<l[2]or l[0]<l[1]>l[2]or f(l[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIccqJ9rYKjYxL0UjJ9og1i4n2jDWJifaKDa/SAEkYAMSsIMKpAHVGFrFamr@LyjKzCsB8qMNdRSMdBSMwaRhrOZ/AA)

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKjGvUkOjQDdZU0sjD0jaGaTlFykU6CTr5Clk5ilUZRZo5OjkRBtaxQJJI6tYTc3/BUWZeSUKaRrRsZpccLYhCkfHCI2rgy6PqcIYQwUWTZiqMOwyRhUwRldhBLH8PwA "Python 2 – Try It Online") using multiplication instead

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <strike>57</strike> 56 bytes

```julia
l->any(p>c<n||p<c>n for(p,c,n)=zip(l,l[2:end],l[3:end]))
```

Basically just totallyhuman's python answer. -1 byte from user71546

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59mm5Sanpn3P0fXLjGvUqPALtkmr6amwCbZLk8hLb9Io0AnWSdP07Yqs0AjRycn2sgqNS8lFsgwBjM0Nf8DKa7S4sy8dAWnxOJUvZDU4hIuhxIgWZxaoqAEYigkAyWKlRTAFkHkFNI0og11jHQMYzXRBHSMUIXMzVHEFGGCQISi0kjHAMk0RahxRmhiQA7Qvf8B)

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 39 bytes

```julia
f(x,y,z,a...)=x>y<z||x<y>z||f(y,z,a...)
```

Lispy recursion style, aka Dennis's python answer. Returns `true` when a bump exists, otherwise throws an error. This should maybe be 42 bytes since you have to splat it when calling. Eg for `a=[1,2,1]` you call as `f(a...)`. `f(a)=f(a...)` would remove that need, but is longer. I need to get better a recursion, and I don't really like writing code that throws an error.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TaNCp1KnSidRT09P07bCrtKmqqamwqbSDkilacBl/pcWZ@alKzglFqfqhaQWl3A5lADJ4tQSBSUQQyEZKFGspJCUmp6ZB5FTSNOINtQx0jGMBelHE9MxwhA1N0cTji/JKMovL1bwTS3JyE9xLSrKL4KrBCJ0E4x0DFDswqndCM1ROBRCVKTmpfwHAA)

Comment: seems the space after `for` is not necessary ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
▼mεẊ-Ẋo±-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0Pbnntj7c1aULxPmHNur@//8/2kgHCGMB)

Uses Dennis's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 54  + 2 (`-pa`) = 56 bytes

```perl
map$\|=$F[$_-1]!=(sort{$a-$b}@F[$_-2..$_])[1],2..$#F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlpsZWxS1aJV7XMFbRVqM4v6ikWiVRVyWp1gEsaqSnpxIfqxltGKsDYiq71Vb//2@oYASEBv/yC0oy8/OK/@v6muoZGBr81y1IBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>11</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
₋ʁ*0<Ʃ±
```

Outputs 1 if there is a bump, 0 otherwise

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UVP3qUYtA5tjKw9t/P8/2kjHWAeIYwE)

Port of [Wheat Wizard's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155816/77078)

---

## Old way (11 bytes):

```
₋±₋Å1≤ĐŁ↔Ʃ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UVP3oY1A4nCr4aPOJUcmHG181Dbl2Erb//@jjXSMdUx0jGMB)

Returns False if there is a bump, True otherwise

Port of [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155800/77078)

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Batch, <s>126</s> <s>120</s> 114 bytes

I was pretty excited about my first use of the `shift` command.

This script generally works for numbers within 9 digits(no matter positive or negative.)

```
:L
@if %3.==. exit/b
@if %2 gtr %1 if %3 lss %2 goto:e
@if %2 lss %1 if %3 gtr %2 goto:e
@shift
@goto:L
:e
@echo T
```

Comment: An empty response might count as a consistent value, otherwise I think you might be able to save a couple of bytes by moving the `echo T` to the end and jumping to it instead of repeating it. I'm also wondering whether you can save bytes by moving the `@shift` to the beginning of the loop but I'm not so sure whether that helps.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the `if`-golf. I don't see any reason moving `@shift` forward will help save bytes. I will take a look at the possible `shift` movement anyways.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
FreeQ[(d=Differences)@Sign@d@#,-2|2]&
```

Gives the opposite of the test case answers (False and True reversed).  Prepend a `!` to switch to the normal form.

OR

```
Abs@(d=Differences)@Sign@d@#~FreeQ~2&
```

Also reversed output, so replace `FreeQ` with `MatchQ` for normal form.

Explanation: Take the sign of the differences of the sequence.  Iff the resulting sequence includes {1,-1} or {-1,1} there is a bump.  The absolute value the differences of {1,-1} or {-1,1} is 2 in either case.

Shave off another byte by squaring the final list instead of taking the absolute value:

```
FreeQ[(d=Differences)@Sign@d@#^2,4]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7360oNTUwWiPF1iUzLS21KDUvObVY0yE4Mz3PIcVBWUfXqMYoVu1/QFFmXkl0mr5DdXWtTrUhCOsYQUgdKA/ON4bxETJwMZguYzBtDOUbgXXXxv4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 35 bytes

Includes `+3` for `-p`

`bump.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s%\S+ %$a*1*($a=$&-$')%eg;$_=/-/
```

Run as:

```
bump.pl <<< "3 1 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>101</strike> 97 bytes

```c
r,i;f(a,n)int*a;{for(i=n|1;--i;a[i]-=a[i-1]);for(r=0;--n>0;r=a[n]<0&a[n-1]>0|a[n]>0&a[n-1]<0|r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLNboQgEIDvPsVkk22ggYRR9y@svsjWg7F1w6G0Yb2pz25xu6alEigHCTN8n8NAw69NM02GKdmSmmmqdPdcy779MEQVekDJuZL1RVW8sF@OFZVzzhTCZnQppLFxXZ3Fk51suhTDvC6X9VkMhspxsl54r5UmNOkTsGMOdG@3Di8VFNCP8h79NDbeks329UVvGLTkvoWBoFQmDpd@c4AQQlMGuEKzBWWQBunMbljR@S@aRX6fM8hWgp0jCFew8wn2jiALCvY@wcGtIHaKA4N85Tj@dYTrOPocJ7eVsWacfA4UP5IsZkDhawc@3uDMR4tA9CqW55j@41IxfSjG6Qs)

Differences the list, then looks for two neighboring differences that are not zero and have opposite sign.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), 78 bytes

*Variant: loop*

```
r,i;f(a,n)int*a;{for(r=n>2,i=0;i<n-2;)r=(a[i++]-a[i])*(a[i]-a[i+1])<0&&r;i=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdPdboIwFAfwe57ihETTakloAT9S2Ys4LoiOpclWFyS7ITw7ayvooE2oN8ih/Z0/R3uJPi@Xvq@J4BUqicRCNpuSt9WtRnUu3xgReczFSUaM4zpH5Vlst0WkLgXe6DvzfUsLfIrX65qLvOZd/3sTV/gS9wYpDjYlAX2VOGgDGD4/tSpVgMI2xPxZVW3B7Bm6ctUNw2uXtXt1DQmYNNxaJNQCnZxi69HUQSH8D9HZITv9vAsCHe27FBKNr6ILzce9oecCcmi7hzKy73J1hVMEKmOFzDICMR5amfk8izyYeOzhAYUlkhGgFmmKMzIZSQJsUU3UIks1xZma/lOJR9yUQGLBpjiDswm8nDhzwZkD3k3gZBHeueCdA95PE/tMY08gtWxTnNmHub2c@@CyDw77OP0JfYZ9dNlHh03jF574yDR2jftRndvDodOwV2pKnTZ12eMBZJ5/P8qcNnPZiTVwrw7qNTO7g6nOO6ST9L5nk6bODunQoev/AA)

*Variant: recursive*

```
f(a,n)int*a;{n=(n<3)?0:((a[--n]-a[--n])*(a[n]-a[n-1])<0&&((n<2)?1:f(a,n+1)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdPNjoIwEAfwO08xIdG0WhLagl9gfBCXA9Fl02S3bpTshfDsbCmgQptQLoQ/7W@G0V6Cr8ulaQqUE4mFLFd5UskjkinHp/CAUH4OApkF3Q2v1LN@kgHNcBoul0gtZfhED1pYU4xxUjd/N3GFb/EokSJhlRNo7xJ7lQf99XtXUQHIr3ycPNPidge9RxzDRKQyEes1htcuY/fi6hPIzyJ7Q4ZLqAXKCCg2Xo0d5MN7E7XZZN2@rz2vbe0nFxINn9IG5eejpOcMjlDVnTKwH3JxhTQA1WOB9DICIe5L6fk8w8QbeazzgMIcyQhQg9ThhOQDSYDNqlwtMlQdTtToTSUO7UYEuAHrcALHI3i@49gGxxZ4M4L5LLyxwRsLvB137DKNLYHIsHU4sXdTe77vnc3eWez9@Cd0GfbeZu8tNg1fOHeRaWgbd5dO7f7QtbBT15RabWqzhwPIHP9@lFltZrO5MXCnCuozY7OCTqcVolH3rmeTRtYKUV@hbv4B)

The criteria is that `a[i]-a[i+1] and a[i+1]-a[i+2]` are non-zero and have opposite sign. `i=r` is just a way to return the value ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644860/function-returns-value-without-return-statement)).

P. S. Additional two test cases may reveal bugs: `{ 1, 2, 1, 2, 2 }` and `{ 2, 2, 1, 2, 1 }`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: By the way, I think `a[--n]-a[--n]` has undefined behaviour and `a[i++]-a[i]` has unspecified behaviour. Doesn't matter since they seem to work with gcc in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
0∨.>2×/2-/⊃,⊃,⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb/00Dko44VenZGh6frG@nqP@pq1oHgRf//lwBlqx/1bn3UuagIyEx71LvLSj0tMTNHHcgCihc96m5Rz89Wr@V61LtGAQJKFAy4NHQMNWFsQwUjBWS2IZhtCGYbIYkbI7FBqhBsYyS9RlC9xlC9hlzGCoZwthHCTAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 43 bytes

```
.+
$*
1`(1+)1¶\1¶1\1|¶(1+)(?<!\2¶\2)¶(?!\2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLMEHDUFvT8NC2GCA2jDGsObQNJKBhb6MYYwQUNdIECtgD2Zr//xtyGXEZAgA) Takes input on separate lines and outputs 0 or 1. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1`            |
```

Count at most one matching regex.

```
  (1+)1¶\1¶1\1
```

Match a number that is surrounded by greater numbers on both sides.

```
               ¶(1+)(?<!\2¶\2)¶(?!\2)
```

Match a number that is not surrounded by greater or equal numbers on either side, i.e. both are less.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 91 bytes

```
def f(a):return[i for i,j in enumerate(a[1:-1])if(j>max(a[i+2],a[i])or j<min(a[i+2],a[i]))]
```

An empty array is a falsey value, while a populated array is truthy

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>50</s> 47 bytes

```perl6
{?grep {0>(.[1]-.[2])*[-] .[^2]},.rotor(3=>-2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v9o@vSi1QKHawE5DL9owVlcv2ihWUytaN1ZBLzrOKLZWR68ovyS/SMPY1k7XSLP2vzVXcWKlQppGtKGOgpGOgmGsJpoIEBkDBf8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## **GFORTH 71 Bytes**

```
: B ROT 2DUP = -1 = IF DROP ROT = -1 = IF  ELSE ." TRUE " THEN THEN ;
```

Output:

```
1 2 1 B TRUE  ok
19 4 19 B TRUE  ok
5 4 6 B  ok
```

Answer (score 0):

## Elm, 102 bytes

```
f a b=case b of
 c::d::e->a c d::f a(d::e)
 _->[]
a g=case g of
 []->1<0
 i::k->i<0||a k
a<<f(*)<<f(-)
```

### Explanation

This works very similar to [my Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155816/56656) answer.  Except Elm is missing all of the functions that do stuff so I had to make every thing from the ground up.  You can test it by running the following [here](http://elm-lang.org/try)

```
import Html exposing (text)
f a b=case b of
 c::d::e->a c d::f a(d::e)
 _->[]
a g=case g of
 []->1<0
 i::k->i<0||a k
g=a<<f(*)<<f(-)
s x=case x of
 True->"True"
 False->"False"
main=g[1,1,1,1,1,0,1]|>s|>text
```